# JWT Auth works with Authorize Attribute but not with [Authorize (Policy = "Administrator")]

Tags: c#, oauth, .net-core, jwt, asp-net-core-spa-services

I have a .NetCore 2.2 Application using Json Web Tokens to authenticate and authorize users.

When I add the [Authorize] Attribute to my controllers, I am able to add the Bearer Token to any requests to those controllers and interact with data.

When I change the Auth attribute to include a role, e.g. [Authorize (Policy="Administrator")] the requests always return a 403.

The User.cs model contains a Role enum with values User/Administrator.

Within Startup.cs I have added RequireRole/RequireAuthenticatedUser.

See Startup.cs

```
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();

        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddJsonOptions(options => { options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; });

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });

        #region JWT
        // Configure AppSettings and add to DI  
        var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

        // Configure jwt authentication
        var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);

        // Add Jwt Authentication Service
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
        #endregion

        #region Add Transient DI
        services.AddTransient<IPlayerService, PlayerService>();
        #endregion

        #region Add Authorization
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Administrator",
                p => p.RequireAuthenticatedUser().RequireRole(Role.Administrator.ToString())
            );
            options.AddPolicy("User",
                p => p.RequireAuthenticatedUser().RequireRole(
                    new[] { Role.User.ToString(), Role.User.ToString() }
                )
            );
        });
        #endregion

        #region Cookies
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options => {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/User/ErrorNotAuthorised";
        options.LoginPath = "/User/ErrorNotAuthenticated";
    });
        #endregion
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            // seeder recreates and seeds database on each execution
            new DataSeeder(new PlayerService(), new ClubService(), new TeamService(), new TeamPlayerService(), new UserService()).Seed();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseCors(x => x
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader());

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });


        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Sample controller method:

```
    // POST: api/Player
    [Authorize(Policy="Administrator")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public void Post([FromBody] Player player)
    {
        _service.AddPlayer(player);
    }
```

This controller method returns a 403 unauthorized request from all interactions. I think my JWT token doesn't contain the Role value, but I'm not sure how to check or how to include it.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

[Watch on Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqjiE.png)

Users class

```
    public enum Role
{
    Administrator,
    User
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT 2:

So all that is really needed for the JWT to use Roles as a form of authentication is included in the Startup.cs function ConfigureServices below. I left out the JWT class, and have also included that below.

I changed the auth attribute on controllers to look for Roles = "Administrator" instead of Policies.

Startup.cs

```
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();

        // Configure AppSettings and add to DI
        var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

        // Configure jwt authentication
        var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);

        // Add Jwt Authentication Service
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
```

JWT Helper class that previous I did not understand:

```
    {       
     // generate Jwt token
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.Id.ToString())
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(50),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        user.Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
         return user;
```

}

Sample of controller w/ Role attribute:

```
            [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] Player player)
    {
        _service.AddPlayer(player);
    }
```

Finally, most of this is obvious and I should've knew before I started the project never mind this post - but updating so anyone who comes across this in the future sees the more appropriate route.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on a controller action that has the Authorize attribute, but no role requirements. Inspect the User object, and specifically the Claims collection. Does it contain any roles? IIRC there is also a static property in there somewhere which indicates the Type of the claim considered to be the role claim - something like RoleClaimName. Does it match the role claims’ Type?

Comment: @sellotape Thanks for your reply. I can't access the contents of [Authorize] when debugging, or more than likely, I'm not putting the breakpoint at the right place. When I debug the controller it only allows me to place the breakpoint on the first line inside of the controller method, and when the bp hits, I can see the contents of the EFCore database, where I can see Users table. But this is of no help in relation to Claims collection etc, which I am not sure how to view. Could you possibly elaborate? Thanks again.

Comment: Just open QuickWatch when on a breakpoint anywhere inside the action and type in User - you’ll see it.

Comment: @sellotape I've added an image of the Watch on User, with the Claims expanded. I don't see any roles. Is this the problem or am I missing something on the watch?

Comment: You can see the claim name (Type) there: nbf, exp, iat, etc.  Do any of the ones further down look "role-like"?  Also the visible ones are issued by "LOCAL AUTHORITY"; they are based on the Windows user of the app pool, or you (if you used Windows authentication on the website, which I'm suspecting not).  If there are also any from another issuer, then ignore all the Windows ones.

Comment: @sellotape none of them resemble "role-like" names. I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong in the Startup.cs, as the answer by Dmitry suggests, however I can't get it working still, after implementing all the code he has left. Where he says 'AdminRoleNameFromToken' I think this should be the number from the enum 'role', but this still doesn't work. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `Role` claims are picked up from `JWT` token. [Role claim name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/technical-reference/the-role-of-claims) can be set this way:

```
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,

        RoleClaimType = "role" // same name as in your JWT token, as by default it is 
        // "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" 
    };
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            var jwt = (context.SecurityToken as JwtSecurityToken)?.ToString();
            // get your JWT token here if you need to decode it e.g on https://jwt.io
            // And you can re-add role claim if it has different name in token compared to what you want to use in your ClaimIdentity:  
            AddRoleClaims(context.Principal);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };

});

private static void AddRoleClaims(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    var claimsIdentity = principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    if (claimsIdentity != null)
    {
        if (claimsIdentity.HasClaim("role", "AdminRoleNameFromToken"))
        {
            if (!claimsIdentity.HasClaim("role", Role.Administrator.ToString()))
            {
                claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", Role.Administrator.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I would re-configure your policy as

```
options.AddPolicy("Administrator", policy => policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                    context.User.IsInRole(Role.Administrator.ToString())
                ));
```

Comment: Hi, what should the 'AdminRoleNameFromToken' be? I have attached the user class to the original question. I have tried Administrator as a string, 1 as an Enumerator, and various other elements that appeared on the Claims collection. I'm not sure what I should be looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @StephenMcGowan I don't know what is inside your JWT token. You can check that yourself. See lines where you get string to var jwt. Debug your code -get jwt variable value and go to jwt.io site to decode it and see what comes to you. Does it make sense?

Comment: Okay so I've figured out where I went wrong. Primarily, I tried to copy another project instead of understanding JWTs, claims etc. I'll update to show the changes I've made to Startup.cs, and how Roles were more suitable to use. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @StephenMcGowan You are welcome, feel free to mark as answer or vote up the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I misused the Policy extension of the Authorize attribute.

I should have been using [Authorize(Roles = "")].

I updated the question to reflect my mistake.